# Insert string between two points with PHP

Tags: php, html

How would I insert text between two comments like the ones below with PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- BEGIN INSERT 1 -->

<!-- END INSERT 1 -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just insert after first tag ?

```
$afterinsert = str_replace( "INSERT 1 -->" , "INSERT 1 -->\n".$toinsert , $beforeinsertion );
```

If you want to insert only when there are both tags, use preg_replace.

Answer (score 6):

```
$after = preg_replace(
    "/<!-- BEGIN INSERT 1 -->\s*<!-- END INSERT 1 -->/",
    "<!-- BEGIN INSERT 1 -->".$insert."<!-- END INSERT 1 -->", 
    $before);
```

Answer (score 3):

a little more context might be helpful. it could be as easy as:

```
<!-- begin insert 1 -->
<?php echo 'text to be inserted'; ?>
<!-- end insert 1 -->
```

what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. It's using `substr_replace()`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

```
<?php

$stringToInsert = "tesssst";
$oldString = "<!-- BEGIN INSERT 1 --><!-- END INSERT 1 -->";
    
$newString = substr_replace($oldString, "-->" . $stringToInsert . "<!--", strpos($oldString, "--><!--"), strlen($stringToInsert));
```