# Replace everything between two tags

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert string between two points with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355213/insert-string-between-two-points-with-php)

How can I replace everything between `<!-- START NOT PRINT -->` and `<!-- END NO PRINT -->`?

The following code works well, but whenever there are two or more instances, it goes wrong.

It then replaces everything between the first tag and the last tag. But it should remove everything between two tags which belongs together. This is my code:

```
$pageData['raw_content'] = preg_replace('/<!--[ ]*START[ ]*NO[ ]*PRINT[ ]*-->(.*)<!--[ ]*END[ ]*NO[ ]*PRINT[ ]*-->/si', '', $pageData['raw_content']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert string between two points with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355213/insert-string-between-two-points-with-php); or [PHP Replace Between Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465620/php-replace-between-tags) or the many other duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are matching greedily.

You need a [non-greedy modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy):

```
'/<!--[ ]*START[ ]*NO[ ]*PRINT[ ]*-->(.*?)<!--[ ]*END[ ]*NO[ ]*PRINT[ ]*-->/si'
```

Notice that `.*` has become `.*?`.

Comment: This is sometimes called a lazy modifier, correct?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Yep :-)

Comment: just `/print \-\-\>([.\w\W]*?)\<\!\-\- end/ui`

Comment: Thanks, it works :). But I still don't understand why.

Comment: @Kevin: `.*` matches as many characters as possible. `.*?` matches as few characters as possible.